# Don't set vertical-align for element in div

Tags: html, css

I have a datalist with item template.

```
 <asp:DataList ID="DataList1" Width="100%" runat="server" RepeatColumns="3" RepeatDirection="Horizontal">
  <ItemTemplate >
     <div style="text-align:center;margin-bottom:5px;vertical-align:bottom;clear:both">  <a href='<%# Eval("Url") %>' rel='prettyPhoto[gallery1]' style='margin:10px;margin-bottom:0px; text-align: center'> <img src='<%# Eval("Url") %>' width='180'  /></a>
      <br /><label ><%# Eval("Name") %></label>  </div>
   </ItemTemplate>
  </asp:DataList>
```

I set datasource for this.

My images have diffrent width and height.

When i run this, my images set center of div, but i want set these bottom of div.

I use

> vertical-align:bottom;

but don't set vertical-align.

Comment: To use vertical-align you must also define the div as display:table-cell;

Comment: Thanks, i use display but don't set again.

Answer (score 0):

You need to apply `vertical-align` for `inline` or `inline-block` elements. Look this: http://jsfiddle.net/6HuF9/

Comment: Thanks, i use but don't set :(

Answer (score 0):

Set div's display to inline-block

```
display: inline-block;
```

Comment: Thanks, i use but don't set :(

Comment: Add width to div, eg- width: 200px;

Comment: No, I set width but don't change :(

Answer (score -1):

Try to do `margin-bottom:0px;` on your images.

Comment: Thanks, i use this, but don't set again.